# Accessing properties in collection of items

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a collection of classes. I don't seem to be able to access the properties of my class though. Is this something I can do?

Here is my class clsProj:

```
Option Explicit
Private pValue As String


Public Property Get Value() As String
    Value = pValue
End Property

Public Property Let Value(tempv As String)
    pValue = tempv
End Property
```

And my sub:

```
Sub testtt()

Set cp = New Collection

cp.Add clsProj, "AAA"
cp.Add clsProj, "BBB"

cp("AAA").Value = "OK"

MsgBox (cp("AAA").Value)

End Sub
```

In sum I have a collection of classes clsProj that I index with strings(this is just a test sub) and I want to access properties of the clsProj for a given collection item ex:AAA in this case. What part is wrong here? I just can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are a bit tricky to understand but when you do they are really useful.  Maybe this will help a bit:

```
Sub testtt()

    Dim cp As Collection
    Set cp = New Collection

    Dim blabla As clsProj
    Set blabla = New clsProj

    Dim blabli As clsProj
    Set blabli = New clsProj

    blabla.Value = "OK"
    blabli.Value = "KO"

    cp.Add blabla, "AAA"
    cp.Add blabli, "BBB"

    MsgBox (cp("AAA").Value)
    MsgBox (cp("BBB").Value)

    Set blabla = Nothing
    Set blabli = Nothing

End Sub
```

**EDIT: mixing `Collection`, `Class` and `For...Next` loop:**

```
Sub testtt()

    Dim cp As Collection
    Set cp = New Collection

    Dim blabla As clsProj
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set blabla = New clsProj

        '"OK" value + a special character from ASCII table
        blabla.Value = "OK " & Chr(32 + i)

        cp.Add blabla, CStr("AAA" & i)

        Set blabla = Nothing
    Next i

    'Test calling collection by key
    MsgBox cp("AAA5").Value

    'Test calling collection by item number and print it in
    '"Immediate" window (ctrl+g to show that window from VBA editor)
    For i = 1 To cp.Count
        Debug.Print cp(i).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @user2385809; Glad I could help!  I added one more example using a `For...Next` loop :)